# Index and count must refer to a location within the buffer. Parameter name: bytes

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

Hello guys im getting This error please see the attachment >> `Index and count must refer to a location within the buffer. Parameter name: bytes`

[image]

When im using debugger i dont get this error and everything goes fine i cannot understand what this error is

this is my server code :

```
 IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 27015);
            Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
            sck.Bind(ipEnd);
            sck.Listen(100);

            Socket clientSocket = sck.Accept();

            string[] fNames = new string[3];
            fNames[0] = "01.jpg";
            fNames[1] = "02.jpg";
            fNames[2] = "03.jpg";

            string filePath = "D:\\";

            byte[] FilesCount = BitConverter.GetBytes(fNames.Count());


            clientSocket.Send(FilesCount);

            for (int i = 0; i < fNames.Count(); i++)
            {
                byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fNames[i]);
                byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath + fNames[i]);
                byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];
                byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);

                fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
                fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
                fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);

                clientSocket.Send(clientData);
            }

            clientSocket.Close();
```

And Client:

```
   Socket clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
        clientSock.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("46.49.70.30"), 27015);


        byte[] clientData = new byte[1024 * bt];
        string receivedPath = "D:/df/";

        byte[] FileQuantityByte = new byte[1024];
        clientSock.Receive(FileQuantityByte);
        int FileQuantity = BitConverter.ToInt32(FileQuantityByte, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < FileQuantity; i++)
        {
            int receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData);

            int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(clientData, 0);
            string fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientData, 4, fileNameLen);

            //Console.WriteLine("Client:{0} connected & File {1} started received.", clientSock.RemoteEndPoint, fileName);

            BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath + fileName, FileMode.Append));
            bWrite.Write(clientData, 4 + fileNameLen, receivedBytesLen - 4 - fileNameLen);

            //Console.WriteLine("File: {0} received & saved at path: {1}", fileName, receivedPath);

            bWrite.Close();
        }

        clientSock.Close();
```

EDIT : http://imageshack.us/f/202/errbk.jpg/

Comment: do an assert before that line and verify that clientData length is at least 4+fileNameLen. If it works fine with debugger I suspect it is a timing issue. Doesn't clientSock.Receive() returns whatever bytes are available in the buffer at the time of call? Alternatively put a 1 second delay before each call to Receive and see if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is telling exactly what the problem is: one of your parameters isn't what you think it should be.

What is the length of `clientData`? What is the value of `fileNameLen` when you call `Encoding.ASCII.GetString`? What is the value of `bt`, which is used to initialize your `clientData` array?

If this doesn't happen in the debugger, then add some code to output the values of `clientData` and `fileNameLen` before the call.

One problem is that `clientSock.Receive` might not get all of the data at once. If you're sending an especially large file, it's possible that `clientSock.Receive` will return without reading everything. As documentation for [Socket.Receive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff.aspx) says:

> If you are using a connection-oriented Socket, the Receive method will read as much data as is available, up to the size of the buffer.

It's possible that not all of the data is available yet, or that the buffer is smaller than the file size. To ensure that you get all of the data, you have to do this:

```
int totalBytesRead = 0;
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = clientSock.Receive(clientData, totalBytesRead,
    clientData.Length - totalBytesRead, SocketFlags.None)) != 0)
{
    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
}
```

`Receive` will return 0 when there is no more data available. Only then can you be sure that you've received all of the data.

Comment: how can i apply this to Async socket, please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29102980/sending-large-message-with-socket-throws-exception?noredirect=1#comment46439159_29102980

Answer (score 2):

Solution is simple. 
I've got similar problem on `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array[byte], index, array[byte].Length)`.
Problem is that method will **TAKE** some count of bytes **FROM** some position in  your array, so you must take not `array[byte].Length`, but less than `array[byte].Length - index`.

If your array has 10 elements and you want to take all from 5th position, you can't take 10 elements.

**So, again** — `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array[byte], FROM, TAKE)`