# index and count must refer to a location within the buffer. parameter name bytes

Tags: c#, arrays, tcpclient

It throws an index and count must refer to a location within the buffer. parameter name bytes exception when more than 3 clients are connected to to the server & the byte data is declared as a global variable.

```
private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)        
{           
    try
    {
        clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);

        Data msgReceived = new Data(byteData);
        //Accordingly process the message received
        switch (msgReceived.cmdCommand)
        {
            case Command.Login:
                //lstChatters.Items.Add(msgReceived.strName);
                break;

            case Command.Logout:
                lstChatters.Items.Remove(msgReceived.strName);
                break;

            case Command.Message:
                break;

            case Command.List:
                lstChatters.Items.AddRange(msgReceived.strMessage.Split('*'));
                lstChatters.Items.RemoveAt(lstChatters.Items.Count - 1);
                txtChatBox.Text += "<<<" + strName + " has joined the room>>>\r\n";
                break;
        }

        if (msgReceived.strMessage != null && msgReceived.cmdCommand != Command.List)
            txtChatBox.Text += msgReceived.strMessage + "\r\n";

        byteData = new byte[1024];

        clientSocket.BeginReceive(byteData,
                                  0,
                                  byteData.Length,
                                  SocketFlags.None,
                                  new AsyncCallback(OnReceive),
                                  null);

    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException)
    { }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ClientTCP: " + strName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

And this is class data used to manage the data communication between server and client:

```
class Data
{
    //Default constructor
    public Data()
    {
        this.cmdCommand = Command.Null;
        this.strMessage = null;
        this.strName = null;
    }

    //Converts the bytes into an object of type Data
    public Data(byte[] data)
    {
        //The first four bytes are for the Command
        this.cmdCommand = (Command)BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);

        //The next four store the length of the name
        int nameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 4);

        //The next four store the length of the message
        int msgLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 8);

        //This check makes sure that strName has been passed in the array of bytes
        if (nameLen > 0)
            this.strName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 12, nameLen);
        else
            this.strName = null;

        //This checks for a null message field
        if (msgLen > 0)
            this.strMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 12 + nameLen, msgLen);
        else
            this.strMessage = null;
    }

    //Converts the Data structure into an array of bytes
    public byte[] ToByte()
    {
        List<byte> result = new List<byte>();

        //First four are for the Command
        result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)cmdCommand));

        //Add the length of the name
        if (strName != null)
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(strName.Length));
        else
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

        //Length of the message
        if (strMessage != null)
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(strMessage.Length));
        else
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

        //Add the name
        if (strName != null)
            result.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strName));

        //And, lastly we add the message text to our array of bytes
        if (strMessage != null)
            result.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strMessage));

        return result.ToArray();
    }

    public string strName;      //Name by which the client logs into the room
    public string strMessage;   //Message text
    public Command cmdCommand;  //Command type (login, logout, send message, etcetera)
}
```

Comment: Better post the exact exception, with the stacktrace. Also, this byteData does not appear to be global.

Comment: Is it possible that you send a message greater than the size of `byteData` (1024)?

Comment: One bad assumption you're making (although I don't *think* it's causing your specific issue) is that your call to `BeginReceive(byteData,0,byteData.Length...` is going to populate the buffer with `byteData.Length` bytes of data. Note the return value for [`EndReceive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wtt64b) that your code is currently ignoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the *first* issue, don't have `byteData` be a global. Make it a local instead:

```
private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)        
{          
    byte[] byteData;
```

Then, pass it as the `state` parameter to [`BeginReceive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxkwh6zw.aspx):

```
 byteData = new byte[1024]; //Line 1

 clientSocket.BeginReceive(byteData,
                                      0,
                                      byteData.Length,
                                      SocketFlags.None,
                                      new AsyncCallback(OnReceive),
                                      byteData);
```

And the recover it from the [`IAsyncResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.aspx) before using it when you've finished receiving:

```
clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);
byteData = (byte[])ar.AsyncState;

Data msgReceived = new Data(byteData); //Line2
```

---

Of course, having fixed this, you still have another issue I alluded to in my comment - there's no guarantee on how much data will have been returned into the buffer - you need to examine the return value from [`EndReceive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wtt64b). You may have to combine multiple calls to `Receive` (or it's moral equivalents) until you actually build up a message. There's no one-to-one correspondence between calls to `Send` at one end and calls of `Receive` at the other.

Finally, you've indicated that you're using `TcpClient`, and yet you're using operations from the `Socket` class? Any reason why you're not using the `NetworkStream` that `TcpClient` gives you? (Not that it makes too much difference here).

Comment: i am using a socket, and i am experiencing the same issue, pls see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665162/index-and-count-must-refer-to-a-location-within-the-buffer-parameter-name-byte how do i apply this solution